# What is the result when adding time stamp with a numeric variable?

Tags: timestamp, addition, labview

I'm trying to make a time counter to reset a button. I want to reset it after 60 seconds, but no state machine has helped me.

The "best" solution I could think of was a time feedback compared to the limit time (aka initial time + 60 seconds).

The thing is: "add funcion" only allows one time stamp variable and the other should be numeric, but how do I know what this numeric means, in terms of time measurement?

If I add 60, will it be 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 60 years?

I've tried to do a state machine, but It was cousing other problems in my software...

the result should be "start time" + 60 seconds

[image: diagram]

---

**Update!**

I've seen some videos, a guy made a timer and I've adapted to my problem, but the comparison don't work (i've waited for 5 minutes max).
I'll try @John Covil 's  idea, but just to let you know what I've been working on, if you want to know :)
http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/2crr0ck/9

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find out would be to branch the output of the CurrentTimestamp function, connect one directly to an indicator, and the other after adding 1, hmm?

Internally, Labview measures time as seconds since midnight 1904-01-01, so adding 1 means adding one second. And since time in LabView has a resolution higher than one second, you can add fractions of a second.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be working at this scale, I'd use the Tick Count function from the Timing palette. You know you're always working in ms, and it's easy to scale into DBL seconds, if you want, or just make your limit 60,000.

The tick count doesn't include error I/O, so if you're using it and ever worry about dataflow and when you get the timer value precisely, you can always make a wrapper to enforce the dataflow.

In the snippet below, the case structure just inside the while loop has an empty False case that just sets defaults on the two outputs. The rest of the code you can see in the two screenshots below. Also included is the code in that ms timer Wrapper VI that I use out of habit.

[image: False state in inner case structure]

[image: True state in inner case structure]

[image: Tick Count Wrapper diagram]

Comment: You'll also want some kind of state logic to remember that you've already set the start time of the button press, if you want to capture a full 60 seconds of the button being pressed. In your original snippet, it's always examining whether you are 60 seconds after the loop originally started.

Comment: This solution was the first one I've tested, but unfortunately it didn't worked and I have no idea why...
Well, I haven't tried with 2 case structures, so I'll try this too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: LabVIEW timestamps in the background are simply [a number of seconds since 1/1/1904](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7900/en/), so adding a number to it will add seconds.

Longer answer: This functionality seems suspect to me. I may be wrong, but I am guessing you are trying to avoid multiple button presses while you are doing something else. I would think a safer of way of doing this would be to set the button to latching functionality and to instead set it to "Disabled and Greyed Out" for 60 seconds. That would inform the user that their input was received and the button cannot be pressed again.

Comment: You got the idea, its a little bit different. I'm trying to do a save button that saves 5 minutes of data (but for testing purposes, i'm doing with 1 minute). This button solution is very nice, but I also need that saving process disables after this time...

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a simple VI](https://github.com/integrationcraft/Simple-LabVIEW-Logging-Timer-) that does what I think you are trying to do? Try running the VI and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So, given solutions worked, but my boss wanted something that consumes less from processor. The solution was quite simple, but I didn't knew how to grab first value of timestamp.

We've used a timestamp loop, which was the inputs of a switch. It also had an boolean loop, that used the first value true, so I could grab first value of the timestamp.
When I press save button, this system register the timestamp value when I pushed the button, after this, I measure continuous values of timestamp and subtract from first value. This results in a difference between moments and it was compared to a int value (in seconds), that would turn false my save button.

I'll upload print when I can :)
Thanks for all the support, I learned a lot!

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/1z2oyop.png
Red blocks are parts of the saving diagram, not related to the questoin